# How to execute a javascript or node.js file in CD pipeline in VSTS so that it is replaced by secrets from keyvalue vault?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I need an understanding about a requirement for Microsoft Azure VSTS CD pipeline.
Let me define scenario please help me with steps or idea if possible.

Let VSTS CI creates an artifact file which contains a JS file which has has some properties that will be replaced based on different environments from Key Value vault.

I need to know how to pull that JS file from artifact folder and execute that javascript or node.js file and execute it so I can replace it with specific environment key value vault values? What trigger or steps shall I use or what steps in CD so I can pull up the JS file and execute the file so I can access the KeyValue vault with respective environment values?

Kindly someone share your ideas or even steps. Request for your kind help and cooperation.

Searching for any guidance in internet to start off. I am absolutely new to this technology finding it difficult to locate some useful resources so far.

Comment: So you have a js file and you want to replace some strings in the file with another strings that came from Key Value vault?

Comment: How are things going? Does my answer give you any help?Please let us know if there is any progress

Answer (score 0):

> how to pull that JS file from artifact folder and execute that
>   javascript or node.js file and execute it so I can replace it with
>   specific environment key value vault values?

Here has a task can used to pull the JSON file and replace variable in file, you can use [File transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops) task to achieve it.

Specified the file path you want to pull in **Package or folder**. And choose your file format. **Note**: The task just support transform JSON and XML file until now.
You can check this docs to learn more [details and example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#json-variable-substitution) about variable substitution.

[image]

And then, for **Key Vault value**, it has been well integrated into **"variable groups"**. In Variable group configuration, there has a little radio button. Enable it, select the correct subscription and Key Vault name.

[image]

After configuration, add this variable group into your pipeline.